# Who has the right to bestow a professor title? (government or university)

Tags: professorship, titles

In my country (Vietnam), the professor title is bestowed by a national council. In Korean or USA, it is bestowed by the university. What about other countries (e.g. Japan, France, Germany, Australia, England, Russia)? And if the title is bestow by the university, is it still recognized when the person who hold the title move to other university?

Comment: I think your first question is very broad. We can't answer it for every country.

Comment: Of course I didn't expect you give me the answer for every country. But what about your country and some country, or some academic system you know?

Comment: What does it even mean to "bestow a title"? If I decide to start the Institute of Scholarly Basket Weaving out of my garage and appoint myself Full Professor of General Basket Weaving, have I bestowed that title on myself? (And who has the right to tell me I don't have the right to do that?)

Comment: I'm sorry if I used the wrong word. I mean to "promote a person as professor". So you mean that in your country, the title is bestowed/promoted by the institute/university? And you are legally a professor in your institute. But in Vietnam you just cannot do that. No one considers you as professor.

Comment: Appointing/promoting a person to a job is not the same thing as bestowing a title on them, so I suggest you [edit] your post to reflect that. But in general, I agree with scaaahu that this question seems like a poll, which we don't generally do here (see the [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: @ff524 In Taiwan, only the Department of Education has the authority to bestow the professorship. One needs to present his/her diploma and thesis/research papers to the government and then they determine if that person is qualified to teach at a university as an assistant/associate/full professor. You can't just declare yourself as a professor without government approval. If you do so, it's criminal offense.

Comment: @ff524 I need to clarify "criminal offense" a little bit. There were cases that people used forged document to gain professorship and then were found guilty. I don't know if they had to serve jail terms. Law here are more generous to academians (they are the most respectable people here).

Comment: @scaaahu Forging documents is fraud; that's a completely different matter.

Comment: @ff524: I meant the title, not the job. If you get a teaching job in a university in Vietnam, you're a lecturer. After quite many years, if your contribution is enough, a council from government will judge and determine to give you the title.

Comment: Then the usage in Vietnam is different from the most common one. Typically, "professor" is used as a job title, like "chief executive officer", "secretary", or "assistant to the regional manager". Some university teachers are professors, some are not, but it is ultimately just a job rank distinction.

Comment: @ff524 Both the OP and I may have an English problem. I interpret "bestow" as "confer". In Taiwan, you do need government approval to declare the title (see my answer). It's like medical doctor or lawyer in the U.S., you need to have license to practice. If my answer is not what I think it is, I would like to withdraw it.

Comment: @scaaahu: your answer exactly what i'm asking for. But I just want to know the situation in some other education systems like Japanese or France. In Vietnam (and also in Asia, I think), professor is not just a job. Professors are respected by all people in the social, not just by their students. I think "professor" is actually a rank of teaching job in Vietnam, but the person who hold that title would hold it for the entire of his or her life. After retiring from the university, he or she is still addressed as "professor". And the title is recognized by every university in the country.

Comment: Adding to the mentioned problems with this question, there is a translation problem here. For example, the German word *Professor* is not the same as the English word *professor:* There are people in Germany who would (correctly) call themselves *professor* but cannot call themselves *Professor.* And that’s not even talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_Germany#Other_professors). So, we would not only need an answer for each country, but you would also need to define *professor* in a language- and system-independent way.

Comment: @JamesDo: Your question, as it is currently structured, might not be a good fit for this site. The issue is that you are asking everyone to provide some information on some countries that the respective users know. This will make it very difficult to select *one* answer as the accepted answer to the question in the end.

Comment: @ff524: "And who has the right to tell me I don't have the right to do that?" - this is indeed a country-dependent matter, as scaaahu already alluded to. For instance, in Germany, the title "Professor" mentioned by Wrzlprmft is legally classified as an "academic title"/"employment title" that may be granted by certain institutions of tertiary education. Consequently, [German criminal code](http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/132a.html) applies, which declares that pretending to be a "Professor" without properly being granted the title is a criminal offence punishable by a fine or imprisonment. ...

Comment: ... And, to be clear about what @Wrzlprmft said (please correct me if I misinterpreted you): "[There are people] who would (correctly) call themselves *professor* but cannot call themselves *Professor*" - "professor" in this sentence is the English word and refers to an English text, whereas "Professor" is the German word in a German, or possibly (as a title in front of a name) in an English text.

Comment: There are ~192 countries. We can't answer for all of them. What is the actual problem that you face? What difference would knowing the answer make to you, what decision would be affected?

Comment: Based on the general patterns of history and scholarship, I suspect that there are a only small number of strong "meta-systems" --- my guess is 1) anarchic systems (like in the USA), 2) nationalized systems (like in France), 3) possibly something derived from UK history, 4) possibly a few other different traditions based in the near East, South Asia, and/or East Asia.

Answer (score 7):

In the United States, personal titles are almost never legally protected or regulated by the government.  This is a strong cultural tradition going back through the origin of the nation, and is in fact encoded in the US Constitution, in [the "Titles of Nobility" clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_of_Nobility_Clause):

> No title of nobility shall be granted by the United States: and no person holding any office of profit or trust under them, shall, without the consent of the Congress, accept of any present, emolument, office, or title, of any kind whatever, from any king, prince, or foreign state.

In the US, then, in general anybody can call themselves any title they feel like, including Professor, Doctor, President, and [Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Norton).  The title, per se, is only a matter of social convention and will be respected or disrespected based on whether other people believe a person deserves it.
The law typically only gets involved from a perspective of fraud, false advertising, public endangerment, etc. if a person uses such a title to give a false impression of your skills and certifications.  To illustrate the distinction: [Dr. Dre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Dre) is perfectly within his rights to use that name, but if he tried to give somebody a prescription, he could be arrested for practicing medicine without a license.

Thus, the US government does not name people professor (except incidentally, if it happens to be running the university, e.g. [NWC](https://www.usnwc.edu/)).  Typically universities name people "professor" as a job title, but in fact, anybody can call themselves a professor or [set up their own fake university](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccredited_institutions_of_higher_education#United_States_of_America) to be a professor at.

Answer (score 4):

In France, the title of *Professeur des Universités* (as well as the lesser *Maître de Conférences*, another tenure-like position comparable to a lecturer) is defined by [a decree of the President of the Republic](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000520453). Both *Professeurs* and *Maîtres de Conférences* are State civil servants and depend on the Ministry of higher education, rather than on their university. They are officially named by a decree of the President of the Republic, but the actual decision process lies with academia:

- A university advertises a professor's position when one of their professors retires, or when the government grants them a new position (pretty rare);
- Prior to the selection process, candidates must be listed as "qualified" for the title of Professor in a given field by an official body, the national council of universities (*Conseil National des Universités*, CNU). Typically, it means that the candidate is a *Maître de Conférences* with enough experience, reputation and publications;
- Candidates for each position are selected by a committee, which includes academics from said university, academics from other institutions and non-academics (of course this is France - and academia, so there are a lot more rules about the composition of those committees);
- The president of the university elects a candidate based on the selection made by the committee (the first ranked is usually chosen, but politics may interfere in the process);
- The next nomination decree lists the chosen candidate among the newly appointed *Professeurs des Universités*.

The process is the same for the *Maîtres the Conférences*, except that the conditions for the initial qualification are not the same (typically, a few publications and some teaching experience).

Comment: I suspect that many continental European countries may also have highly nationalized systems (though with many differences in details) due to the influence of the Napoleonic code on systems of government in continental Europe.  Can people from other continental national confirm?

Comment: This process looks similar to my vague idea of what goes on in Spain. Professors are employees of a public entity, and thus the hiring is subjected to these procedures.

Answer (score 3):

In Taiwan, you need to pass the [Screening of Qualification on Teachers of Junior Colleges and Higher Levels](http://english.moe.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=440&ctNode=412&mp=11) by Ministry of Education to earn the title. In the page it says,

> Assistant professors:
>
> Those who apply for the screening of teacher qualification ...  shall submit: Doctoral Award(s) or other equivalent certificate(s), transcripts and specialized publications ...
>
> Assistant professors
>
> Those who apply for the screening of teacher qualification ... shall submit: Doctoral Award(s) or other equivalent certificate(s), transcripts and specialized publications. ...
>
> Professors
>
> Those who apply for the screening of teacher qualification ... shall submit: Doctoral Award(s) or other equivalent certificate(s), relevant certificate(s) of seniority, transcripts and either one of the important contributions their creations, inventions have made to academia and their important specialized publications.
>
> Those who apply for the screening of teacher qualification ...  shall submit: Certificate(s) of Associate Professor, relevant certificate(s) of seniority, transcripts and specialized publications.
>
> **...**
>
> Those who are employed by schools and do the actual teaching are entitled to apply for the screening ...
>
> The full-time teachers shall send the applications via the schools they serve ...
>
> **...**

and then

> Those who pass the screening of teacher qualification shall be conferred the teacher certificates; the format of the certificates **shall be prescribed by the Ministry**.
> The recognition of the seniority listed on teacher certificates **shall be prescribed by the Ministry**.

I could not find the document in English for moving to other universities at the moment. To the best of my knowledge, the title is transferable when you move to other universities.